# Convert a space separated string to a dictionary element in Python

Tags: python, string

How I can convert the following string to a dictionary element in python?

> David 12 14 15

Dictionary element will be something like:

```
[David] => [12, 15, 20]
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Quick answer

```
>>> s = 'David 12 14 15'.split()
>>> {s[0]:[int(y) for y in s[1:]]}
{'David': [12, 14, 15]}
```

#### Step by step details

First, we split the string on white space:

```
>>> s = 'David 12 14 15'.split()
>>> s
['David', '12', '14', '15']
```

Now, we need two parts of this list.  The first part will be the key in our dictionary:

```
>>> s[0]
'David'
```

The second part will be the value:

```
>>> s[1:]
['12', '14', '15']
```

But, we want the values to be integers, not strings, so we need to convert them:

```
>>> [int(y) for y in s[1:]]
[12, 14, 15]
```

One can make dictionaries by specifying keys and values, such as:

```
>>> {'key':[1,2]}
{'key': [1, 2]}
```

Using our key and value produces the dictionary that we want:

```
>>> {s[0]:[int(y) for y in s[1:]]}
{'David': [12, 14, 15]}
```

Comment: Code is dense. An explanation is always useful, especially for beginner questions.

Comment: @jpaugh Thanks.  I added a breakdown of the steps.

Comment: Thank *you*, for increasing the awesomeness ratio of SO. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You can `split` the string using [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) , and then use [`list.pop(0)`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) to pop the first element to get the key and set the rest of the split list as the value. Example -

```
>>> d = {}
>>> s = 'David 12 14 15'
>>> ssplit = s.split()
>>> key = ssplit.pop(0)
>>> d[key] = ssplit
>>> d
{'David': ['12', '14', '15']}
```

If you want the elements as `int` , you can also use `map` before setting the value to dictionary -

```
>>> d[key] = list(map(int, ssplit))
>>> d
{'David': [12, 14, 15]}
```

For Python 2.x, you do not need the `list(..)` as `map()` in Python 2.x already returns a list.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [2]: line = "David 12 14 15"

In [3]: answer = {}

In [4]: key, vals = line.split(None, 1)

In [5]: answer[key] = [int(i) for i in vals.split()]

In [6]: answer
Out[6]: {'David': [12, 14, 15]}

In [7]: answer['David']
Out[7]: [12, 14, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
line = "David 12 14 15"
parts = line.split()
lineDict = {}
lineDict[parts[0]] = parts[1] + " " + parts[2] + " " + parts[3]
```